# IF/ELSE not displaying the desired results

Tags: php

In this query in looking for comments, and if there are any comments it should be displayed, if there are'nt any comments it should display No comments yet.

The comments are displayed correctly but the if function to display that there arent any comments is not working.

```
$comments = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = '". $_GET['id']."'");

while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array ($comments)) {

    //If there are'nt any results
    if(mysql_num_rows($comment) < 0 ) {
        echo "No comments yet!";

} else {

    //If there are any results
        echo "<p>" . $comment['comment'] . "</p>
            <p><b>" . $comment['author'] . "</b>, " . date("M j, Y ", strtotime($comment["date"])) . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($comment) < 1 ) -- change 0 to 1

Comment: Define exactly what you mean in "not working".

Comment: `(mysql_num_rows($comment) < 0 )` if none are found it'll be 0, but you want smaller than 0 so it goes to the else part. CHange the 0 to a 1 and it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reorganize your code and you have a mistake in the compare for 0 comments:

```
$comments = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = '". $_GET['id']."'");

//If there are'nt any results
if(mysql_num_rows($comments) == 0 ) { // <-- watch for 0 results
    echo "No comments yet!";            
}
else {
  while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array ($comments)) {                        
    //If there are any results
    echo "<p>" . $comment['comment'] . "</p>
    <p><b>" . $comment['author'] . "</b>, " . date("M j, Y ", strtotime($comment["date"])) . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: sp3polz: i tried that to but did not work
PLB: not working = nothing is displayed.
JvdBerg: rearanged the code and changed the number from 0 to a 1..

thx guys!

Comment: Is it me or is that code not completely logic? In the IF function you check whether $comment display more than 0 rows, but you don't define $comment anywhere nor do you execute a query that would give $comment a value (this is only done in the else part)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($comment) < 0 )
```

You can't have less than 0 rows. Change to:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($comment) <= 0 )
```

(or == 0, or really anything that would trigger when it's 0 but not above 0)